# How can I print a Firemonkey form on Windows?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In Delphi VCL it was easy to print a form since the form had a `Print` method. This does not seem to be the case with forms in FMX. Is there an easy way to print a form in FMX on Windows?

Answer (score 5):

The process is as follows:

1. Use the [FMX printing API](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Printing_from_a_FireMonkey_Application).
2. Make a screen shot of your form by calling the [`MakeScreenshot`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TControl.MakeScreenshot) method.
3. Print the screen shot with `Printer.Canvas.DrawBitmap`.

Since `TForm` does not derive from `TControl`, and `MakeScreenshot` is a `TControl` method, you cannot call `MakeScreenshot` on your form. You'll need an overall container for your forms controls on which you can call `MakeScreenshot`.

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately a form does not seem to have a method called MakeScreenShot? Also the vcl GetFormImage seems to have disappeared. Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: MakeScreenshot is  in TControl.

Comment: I am a relative beginner, but since MakeScreenshot is a method of TControl and a form is a TComponent, it seems that MakeScreenShot cannot be used. Correct?

Comment: Well, your form's visual components are all derived from `TControl`. So you'll need to design your IDE so that one `TControl` container contains the client area of your form. And then call `MakeScreenshot` on that.

Comment: This basically works. Thanks. The only thing not working is that the TCharts on the 'form' do not show up on the print.

Comment: Are they inside your container? If so, then I don't know why they would fail to paint.

Comment: Yes they are inside the container (a Tabcontrol). It's weird, Tlabels and TButtons also inside the container are printed without a problem. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @user2297042, could you please edit the question adding the `teechart` tag and posting a simple example code we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here?

Comment: @Yeray It should not be an edit to the question. It should be a new question.